# The execution of the code takes input but doesnot return anything

Tags: c, visual-studio-debugging

How can I get output in this code? As you can see the question for the code which I have written in comments. This is written in C.

```
/*To print prime numbers from n1 to n2 where n1 and n2 are input by user and n1<n2*/
    //please solve this code, i am stuck
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int n1, n2, i, j;
        printf("Enter two numbers");
        scanf("%d\t%d\n", &n1, &n2);
        printf("The prime numbers in betwn %d and %d are:\n", n1, n2);
        for (i = n1; i <= n2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (i = j)
            {
                printf("%d\t", i);
            }
        }
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you meant to write `if (i == j)` and `printf("%d\n", i); and `if (i % j == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d\t%d\n", &n1, &n2);
```

Issue seems here. Input needs to be provided in the same way as specified in the format of scanf(). I suggest changing it to the following for simplicity:

```
scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
```

Another thing: `if (i = j)` , this should be comparison operator instead of assignment.

Since you are trying to print prime numbers in a range, the logic/approach seems incorrect as well.

Answer (score 0):

**To add more detail**:

First, l agree with **dev7060** and thanks to him. There are two aspects which you should pay attention to:

**1)** `%d\t%d\n` means you should input three parameters into the data flow. You can see this which l have tested in my side.

[image]

So please try this like **dev7060** said:

```
scanf("%d%d", &n1, &n2);
```

And **note** when you input one parameter, please first hit a space bar and then input the second parameter. `%d%d` can grab two digits into the input stream before the entry by any space character, such as the TAB key or space bar, or the enter key. So when you enter parameters, you can get them by typing an interval character between them.

**2)** `i=j` means an assignment operation rather than a comparison operation and it always returns true.
You should use `if(i==j)`.

Please refer to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, i, j;
    printf("Enter two numbers");
    scanf("%d%d", &n1, &n2);
    printf("The prime numbers in betwn %d and %d are:\n", n1, n2);
    for (i = n1; i <= n2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (i == j)
        {
            printf("%d\t", i);
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

**In addition**, when you face these issues in VS:

> error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. error
>
> error C4996: 'getch': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated.

These are compiler errors and you should use `scanf_s()` instead of `scanf()` and use `_getch()` instead of `getch()`. You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019).

Comment: _"please first hit a space bar and then input the second parameter"_ -- it would be fine to press Enter between entries, or to use any other combination of whitespace characters, since the `%d` `scanf()` directive automatically discards leading whitespace characters.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for texts. Every decent shell allows text copies.